# Double Intent for call skype/phone

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

Hi I want with the press of the button to either call a phone number or make a Skype call.

**To make the call I use:**

```
Intent phone= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+30 6********7"));
startActivity(phone);
```

Which pops a Window and let me choose from phone app or Skype. When I choose Skype it tries to make a call with Skype founds and not VoIP Skype call.

**I found out that for Skype I need to use :**

```
Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + "user_name"));            
startActivity(skype);
```

Is there a way to **chain** those two intents and whenever I choose **phone app** to run phone Intent and whenever I choose **Skype** to run Skype Intent ?

I know I can make a custom dialog to choose Intent to run and exclude Skype app from **Intent phone**

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way built in android or even if I can make the VoIp call from the number it self (finding the user from phone).

Thank you in advance

Comment: to use a voip in skype you need the username. So basically, you need to a/ have both the user_name in skype and the associated phone number. b/ have the user choose call or skype c/ create the correct intent for the chosen option

Comment: Yes I could do that but recently I saw in an App when the Intent chooser popped and you chose Skype it called the user via VoIP and when you choose phone it called via Phone app

Comment: could be that the intent chooser was local (i.e. 2 activities in that same app with the call and the skype redirection in them)

Comment: When you call 'Intent phone' both Phone app and Skype shows up but if you choose Skype it start's a call with Skype founds.

When you call 'Intent Skype' alone it start's a Skype call to the user via VoIP.

I want to combine those Intents excluding the Skype call from the phone intent